# Gatsby button onClick use Link functionality

Tags: html, gatsby

I want to use Gatsby's Link functionality inside a button. I am doing this cause I am having an easier time formatting the button to look like what I want as opposed messing with the Link formatting.

This is my old code

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
<button>
    <Link to="/event-details">Details</Link>
</button>
```

This is what what I am trying to get to work.

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
<button onClick:'Link to = /page'>Page button</button>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

import `navigate`

```
import { navigate } from "gatsby"
```

then in your button will be

```
<button onClick={()=>{navigate("/page")}}>Page button</button>
```

Comment: Make sure you add `role="link"` for accessibility.  Or you can use a `<a>` with an href and avoid manually managing semantics and accessibility.